# Trying to split string with regex

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to split a string in Python using a regex pattern but its not working correctly.

Example text:

`"The quick {brown fox} jumped over the {lazy} dog"`

Code:

`"The quick {brown fox} jumped over the {lazy} dog".split(r'({.*?}))`

I'm using a capture group so that the split delimiters are retained in the array.

Desired result:

`['The quick', '{brown fox}', 'jumped over the', '{lazy}', 'dog']`

Actual result:

`['The quick {brown fox} jumped over the {lazy} dog']`

As you can see there is clearly not a match as it doesn't split the string. Can anyone let me know where I'm going wrong? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're calling the strings' split method, not re's

```
>>> re.split(r'({.*?})', "The quick {brown fox} jumped over the {lazy} dog")
['The quick ', '{brown fox}', ' jumped over the ', '{lazy}', ' dog']
```